# How to access file tree in hg (mercurial) web interface?

Tags: browser, mercurial, hg

There is a hg web browser here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7

How Can I access file and folder tree of this repository (most recent version) without downloading gz/bz2/zip?

I want to view `hotspot` and `jdk` subrepositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [manifest](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/file/ee67ee3bd597) link on every repository.